# Is there a way to migrate Delphi 2010 forms into Delphi Prism (.Net ) XE forms?

Tags: .net, delphi, forms, delphi-prism

I know that since "native" delphi and delphi.net are different technologies it is unlikely to produce a tool that can migrate your old dfm forms to win forms for delphi prism. However is there a tool that facilitate such migration? Basically I have a "native" delphi project that I want to migrate to delphi .net, it is a desktop application, how do I go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VCL and Winforms are enough different to make such conversion not easy. There are also some components that are Delphi specific without a direct .NET counterpart, and a conversion tool probably would fail if unsupported third party controls are used. The old VCL.NET framework was an attempt to make that transition easier, but failed. A conversion tool may be written, but IMHO it would be of limited use and work for simple forms only. There's no one I am aware of, and because most developers that migrated from Delphi to .NET went the VS/C# way - I see very little advantages of moving a desktop application from Delphi to Prism - there are very little reasons to write one.

Comment: This is very good input as my thinking was to migrate to prism and then to c#. I hoped that this two step migration could be easier as decompiling project to c# and then fixing it up so it works, while not super easy but definitely easier than manual re-write. Now it appears that this was not that good idea to begin with. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The only tool wich i know to port [`Delphi Win32`](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) and `Delphi .Net` Code to [`Delphi-Prism`](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism) is  [`Oxidizer`](http://www.remobjects.com/oxidizer.aspx), but this app does not translate the Delphi forms to Winforms, Oxydizer is good for converting library code and other non-visual related code, however it is still a great option to help you to translate your Delphi code.

you can found more info in this [link](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Oxidizer)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's the forms that worry me most at the moment, though.