# Conversion from Delphi to .NET 4 (Without any tool)

Tags: .net, wpf, delphi, c#-4.0, delphi-2009

One of our clients wants their Delphi application to be converted to .NET 4.0. After reading responses to various similar questions on this site, I've decided to take a step-by-step approach of converting the Delphi code to .NET.

Since I am a .NET developer, I need to first get familiar with Delphi. It is quite difficult to find any single site which provided a comprehensive overview of the concepts of Delphi. Also I haven't still found any site which provides information about the equivalents of Delphi in .NET.
For example what is the equivalent of "stdcall" or "export" in .NET? or what is the equivalent of a particular Delphi datatype in .NET?

Does anyone know about such online resource which provide information about Delphi equivalents in .NET? Also if anyone could provide any tips on this?

Comment: this is far too broad to answer. Read the delphi language guide and take it from there.

Comment: See Embarcadero's documentation wiki here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Main_Page

Comment: I'd like to add that looking for 1:1 mapping between language elements is misguided. If that would cut it, there'd be automated tools for the job. For example the `stdcall` and `export` keywords signal a DLL designed to be used from other applications. There's no direct equivalent in the .NET world because you can't link to a .NET library from a Native application, you need to use all sorts of interop technologies.

Comment: Offtopic maybe, but why not subcontract that work off to someone with Delphi and Delphi Prism experience, that should work way faster than climbing the learning curve yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, the fastest way to do this is to start from scratch. Trying to convert the legacy code from Deplhi to C# is just fraught with issues, and at the end of it, you will have a Delphi-like C# application. The underlying frameworks, VCL in Delphi, and FCL in .NET, have significant architectural differences, so given that the amount of time to convert will be roughly equivalent to the amount of time to develop from scratch, you are dooming yourself to a 2nd class application if you go down the conversion path.

And I might add that I have successfully converted an application framework from Deplhi to Delphi.NET, for use in Visual Studio. I did this to maintain inter-process communication and architectural compatability between the two development environnments. If the benefits of this had not be large, I never would have done the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, there is no direct way to answer this unless deciding to go all the way explaining what Delphi is and how it compares to dotNet.

You might however be interested in knowing that the latest versions of RadStudio do include a Delphi.NET which integrates in VS.

That is probably your shortest and safest path to the job.

For starters, the two versions(although remarkably different) still bear enough similarities to cross compile for the most part - and that would certainly be a start.

I am not sure about the GUI, but as long as the application is using mainstream components, there should be dotNET counterparts.
DevExpress and TMS come to mind, for instance.

Last, but not least, I am confident that if you need any specific help, we'll all be happy to help :)

Andrea

Comment: I would not recomend porting to Delphi Prism mainly because client clearly asked for c# version and also porting from Delphi win32 to Delphi Prism would be almost the same amount of work like porting to c#. Delphi Prism or Oxygene is not Delphi, it's a Object Pascal compiler for .NET. Real Delphi.NET (Delphi 2007 .NET) was discontinued and for very good reasons. For example there is no  class variables in Delphi Prism

Comment: That's partly true, but there are a few things to consider:
1) While it's true the languages are different, there still is a large compatibility degree.
2) It's true that Delphi.NET is not C# but that's not a problem, since there is a wealth of converters including things like Reflector

Plus, while it's impossible to match Delphi and dotNET 1 to 1, it's certainly quicker to do it this way(in my opinion) rather than any other option.

Andrea

Comment: Porting to Prism would also keep the link with the VCL, which is a huge plus, with C# you'll have to use an entirly different framework. Besides with prism you can reuse (most) of your .dfm files, with C# you have to redesign those, way more work.

Comment: Johan, I am not really sure about this one, but I wouldn't count on that too much. VCL for dotNET - as far as I know - has been discontinued. What I meant is that the main component vendors on the Delphi market are also very active on the dotNET side of the world, sometimes bringing in even better quality(think of Steema TChart for instance). 
Still, much work will have to be done on the UI side, I am afraid.

Comment: @Johan there is no VCL in Delphi Prism, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809452/is-there-a-way-to-migrate-delphi-2010-forms-into-delphi-prism-net-xe-forms

Comment: Sorry antonio, I stand corrected

Answer (score 2):

I would take some of automated tools for porting to C# just to relif you the pain of porting different syntax, and after that it's all hand work.

And there is a book for Delphi developers that describes .NET and similarities and differences, [.NET 2.0 for Delphi Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593863) I know that this is other way around but IMO can help

Comment: Thanks @Antonio Bakula. I think [.NET 2.0 for Delphi Programmers](http://www.amazon.com/NET-2-0-Delphi-Programmers-Shemitz/dp/1590593863) together with [Delphi for .NET Developer's Guide](http://www.amazon.com/Delphi-Developers-Guide-Xavier-Pacheco/dp/0672324431/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpi_1) would be really helpful

Comment: -1 what about the link to the VCL and the DFM files? That's where most of the work is....

Comment: automated tools can do that, for example Delphi2CS can convert *.dfm files to c# code. On their site they stated that Delphi2CS can convert VCL components to c#. I didn't use it, so I don't know how this is working, but I did a research what is needed to port big Delphi 2006 system to c#, at the end company that I worked for back then (2007) on my advice cancel porting all together and continue to use Delphi :)